# Creating Trigger using MetadataService Class

Tags: metadata-api

Hi am creating apex trigger using MetaData Service class but i am getting this Exception -

> Line: 13432, Column: 1
>   System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_TYPE: This type of object is not available for this organization faultcode=sf:INVALID_TYPE faultactor=

Sample code -

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service2 = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();  
service2.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service2.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();     
MetadataService.ApexTrigger objTrigger = new MetadataService.ApexTrigger();
objTrigger.type = 'ApexTrigger';
objTrigger.apiVersion = 45.0;
objTrigger.status = 'Active';
objTrigger.fullName = 'TestTrigger';
string str= 'Trigger TestTrigger on Account (After Insert,After update){}';
//apexPage.label = 'TestPage';
objTrigger.content = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(str));
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service2.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { objTrigger });
```

Comment: Hi @Swati, Welcome to SFSE, to get better reponses; please include the code causing the problem.

Comment: Also, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Hi Swati, make sure you read some of the guidelines of this forum https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . Describe what you have analyzed, what you have done and what you want to achieve. We need more context

Comment: hi, did anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

once I also get the same error and the solution for this  error is that you have to pass the session id using @ future annotation in another method Examle

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void deleteBooks(id ids){
    getthesessionid(ids);
}
@future(callout=true)
public static void getthesessionid(id ids){
    String sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
     MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId =sessionId;
```

then your logic.....
note : here ids contaains id of record which i want to delete

Comment: hi Ravinder, what is the underlying problem of this, do you know? I ask this because the error and the suggested solution do not seem related.